# How to write new line with drawText() in magento?

Tags: invoice

I am trying to new line with magento function `drawText();` I was tried below code but it showing all statement like `Line 1! \n Line 1!`

can any body tell me how do i print multiple new lines using below code.

```
 $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Line 1! \n Line 1!'), 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: you can follow this link and try it works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950654/php-pdf-line-break

Comment: add this in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a separate call to $page->drawText for each line.

So for example something like this.

```
$textChunk = wordwrap($value, 20, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
  if ($value!=='') {
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
    $line -=14;
  }
}
```